# how to use contents of <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f91fc5c88d0> in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiondispatch, attr-encrypted

I've uploaded and encrypted two images to my app, and now I need to use them in an `img_tag`. How can I retrieve the contents of this string and display them to the user?

```
Model.document_front: <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f91fc5c88d0>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `path` method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-path

More information here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/8nqssd/actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile/

Comment: The docs say "Uploaded files are temporary files whose lifespan is one request" - is it bad to store them that way? Should uploaded files be saved as something other than `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`?